# Happy 90th Birthday to Our Favorite Ubiquitous Movie Music Composer: John Williams

Tags: discussion

[**Composer John Williams**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Williams) rules the music cinematic world for his unique and catchy music compositions. Tomorrow (2-8-22) he will be 90 years old - congratulations to Mr. Williams! I'll list some of his compositions here for fun. **All links lead to YouTube clips featuring John Williams himself conducting his own music.** Please share your own favorite John Williams composition(s)/soundtracks. You can also include any quips/quotes you especially like from any of the movies he's composed for. I'll start with:

[***Jaws***](https://youtu.be/E-sX2Y0W8l0):

Brody: "*You're gonna need a bigger boat.*"

Quint: *"Farewell and adieu to you, fair Spanish ladies. Farewell and adieu, you ladies of Spain. For we've received orders for to sail back to Boston. And so nevermore shall we see you again."*

I grew up in southern California and, despite having had a previously positive relationship with the ocean while growing up, when I saw *Jaws*, I was absolutely terrified. I rarely went into the ocean again after watching *Jaws*!

I had a hard time choosing between *Jaws* and this next one for first place. John Williams conducts the Wiener Philharmonic for these clips (Note the amazing HD on the Wiener Philharmonic):

[***Star Wars IV - A New Hope (Main Theme)***](https://youtu.be/54hoKbTWon4)

[***The Empire Strikes Back: Imperial March***](https://youtu.be/vsMWVW4xtwI)

Ben Kenobi: "*Mos Eisley spaceport: You will never find a more wretched hive of scum and villainy. We must be cautious.*" Indeed!

Han Solo, exasperated, to Princess Leia: "*No reward is worth this*."

Ben Kenobi: "*The Force will be with you, always.*"

*Star Wars IV* is definitely one of my top five favorite movies of all time. My parents were hesitant about allowing me to see *Star Wars* (but let me see *Jaws* as a kid? WTH?!), but ultimately gave in to my incessant begging and wheedling, and let me see *Star Wars*. I loved it more than anything at the time. As a kid I used to listen to it at night while nodding off to sleep.

Next up is *Jurassic Park* - this is my daughter's favorite John Williams composition and she wanted me to include it in my list. I threw this in for her. John Williams conducting the Vienna Philharmonic:

[***Jurassic Park***](https://youtu.be/-NqaupGcCpw) (T-Rex bellows like whoa)

Finally, [***Close Encounters of the Third Kind***](https://youtu.be/J55Q9cA-DK4) with John Williams conducting the Wiener Philharmonic.

Roy Neary: "*Who are you people*?"

I'll leave it at that for my choices, but would love to know what John Williams compositions are your favorites? Just a bit of fun!

Comment: And of course, it's always worth mentioning that he's a VFW, having served his country with distinction in the US Air Force (as a composer and 'Airman Musician') in the 1950s including a very brief stint in Korea.

Comment: Williams' music was a revelation the first time I heard it (in *Star Wars*) and I still remember the instant recognition I felt the first time I saw *Superman* and *Indiana Jones*.  His scores pretty much defined the sound of the classics of the SF movie genre when I was growing up.  But after the *Star Wars* main theme, my favourite music is probably "Imperial March" from *ESB*.

Comment: @Valorum - Oh, really? I didn't know that! For this post, though, I kept it to music because that is what specifically makes it on topic here at SFF. However, his military service is also duly noted. That said, John Williams truly has a rare gift for music and composition. So many movie soundtracks and themes under his belt. :)

Answer (score 5):

His earliest science fiction theme music was probably [**Lost in Space.**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tQzk09j2lZ8)

Comment: This is interesting to me as well: I'll be watching something and when the credits role, there's John Williams listed as the composer. Thanks for adding an answer. It demonstrates what a long history of music and the movies John Williams has been a part of. :)